# Creating and initializing arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization

I'm learning about Javascript arrays. I understand most of the code, except line 4. Can you please explain what the code in line 4 does, and how it has this output.

```js
var fibonacci = []; //{1}
fibonacci[1] = 1; //{2}
fibonacci[2] = 1; //{3}

for(var i = 3; i < 20; i++){
    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2]; ////{4}
}

for(var i = 1; i<fibonacci.length; i++){ //{5}
    console.log(fibonacci[i]);           //{6}
}
```

`1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181`

Thank you.

Comment: It sets the value at array position i to the sum of the two values before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's Fibonacci sequence. How it works? every number after the first two is the sum of the two preceding ones that's why you have to initialize the first two terms

```
fibonacci[1] = 1; 
fibonacci[2] = 1;
```

on line 1 you create the array and after intializing the first two terms you loop, starting from the third index `var i = 3` to fill the array `fibonacci` with all the terms of the sequence. How? it assigns the sum of the two previous terms to the current one.

ps: in javascript arrays start at index 0

Answer (score 0):

At Line 2 & 3 you set the values for item 1 & 2. Since fibonacci is sum of two values before, the line 4 just sums up the two values before for each element from 3 to 19.